# On a gaussian integral identity and its expansions to complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, gaussian-integral

For $a > 0$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^d$ it is not too hard to show that $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} e^{\langle b \mid x \rangle - \frac{\|x\|^2}{a}} dx = (\pi a)^{d/2}e^{\frac{a}{4}\sum\limits_{i=1}^d b_k^2}$$ Now what about $b \in \mathbb{C}^d$? I know that the formula still works out just fine in that case, but all the references I find just state that this is a simple application of analytic continuation, which is very mysterious to me to be honest. As far as I know, it can be justified by contour integration, but this seems to be quite tedious. However, there is another approach that states that the integral on the left hand side may be seen as a holomorphic function in the variable $b \in \mathbb{C}$ (if we restrict to the case were $d=1$, since knowing this case implies the case of $d>1$) and this holomorphic function agrees on some region with the holomorphic function on the right, so I guess we can somehow deduce, by using the identity theorem, that those two function are actually the same.

> Can someone elaborate on how and why this is justified?

Comment: $|<b,x>| \le ||b||||x||$ means the integral is uniformly convergent (in $b$) on compact subsets of $\mathbb C^d$ so it gives a holomorphic function in the whole $\mathbb C^d$ (again in $b$) since the integrand is obviously so; RHS is also obviously a holomorphic function there coinciding with the integral on the real subspace; the identity principle says that they coincide everywhere since the real subspace has non-isolated points - the whole paragraph above is usually shortened to "analytic continuation"

Comment: @Conrad Why does the real space having non-isolated points already imply, that these two functions must be equal by the identity principle?

Comment: fix a real point eg $0=(0,..0)$ and write the power series for the difference $h=f-g$ there and show that all coefficients are zero - this is standard stuff in power series and is done by an easy induction (try one variable first and see how it works)

Comment: @Conrad Could we also say that since both functions are entire and every ball $B_R(0)$ for $R>0$ has an accumulation point in $\mathbb{R}$ ($0$ would always be such a point) on which these functions agree, that the functions must coincide on $B_R(0)$ by the identity theorem? Since this holds for all $R>0$, we know that the functions indeed are equal. Is that correct?

Comment: sure it is correct